# Why is $x+2y+3z=0$ a plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry

I took this lecture from Sir Denis at OCW about multivariable calculus where he explains vectors and he gives this question at the end of the lecture?

$x+2y+3z = 0$ is a plane.

But I don't really understand why is it a plane, granted the vectors $(x, y, z)$ and $(1, 2, 3)$ are perpendicular as their dot product is $0$ which implies the angle between them is $90^{\circ}$.

But if the angle is $90^{\circ}$, it should be a perpendicular, not a plane.

What am I missing?

Comment: See [Equation of the plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry)#Point-normal_form_and_general_form_of_the_equation_of_a_plane) : "the equation $ax+by+cz+d=0$ represents a plane having the vector $n = (a, b, c)$ as a normal. This familiar equation for a plane is called the general form of the equation of the plane."

Comment: Probably you miss the fact that the vector $(1,2,3)$ is not in plane but is instead orthogonal to it.

Comment: @user can you explain?

Comment: And a plane is uniquely determined by its *normal*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA okay, from what i can grasp. I think you're saying just like the general equation of a circle in 2d, ax+by+cz+d=0 in 3d is the general equation of a plane and whenever an equation is represented as such, it means that the graph of it will be a plane right?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I'm pretty new to the topic of vectors and plane geometry, so can you please provide me some sorta resource where i can study about it?

Comment: Yes; the set of 3D points $(x,y,z)$ that satisfy the equation belong to the plane perpendicular to vector $(a,b,c)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA can you write this as an answer?

Comment: You can see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.6521.pdf) and [here](http://www.descarta2d.com/Exploring%20Analytic%20Geometry%20with%20Mathematica%20(Vossler).pdf)

Comment: What exactly should be explained? That all vectors orthogonal to a direction are coplanar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the set of *all* vectors (in all directions) which are orthogonal to $(1,2,3)$. Therefore, it's a plane.

For instance, the set of all vectors orthogonal to $(0,0,1)$ is the plane $z=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $x=-2y-3z$ each point vector $(x,y,z) = y(-2,1,0)+z(-3,0,1)$ in that set is linear combination of vectors $a= (-2,1,0)$ and $b=(-3,0,1)$. So every point in that set is in a plane spanned with these two vectors.

Answer (score 1):

You say "it should be a perpendicular". But a perpendicular to what ?

The answer is a perpendicular to the vector $(1,2,3)$, which is also a perpendicular to the line of direction $(1,2,3)$, and this is a plane.

---

To prove that the locus is not a single line, one can exhibit three points that are not aligned, such as $(0,0,0), (1,1,-1)$ and $(2,-1,0)$. Clearly, the vectors that they form two by two are not proportional to each other.

Comment: yea perpendicular to the vector, correct.